# container is not defined error for geochart

Tags: angular2-routing

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Container is not defined

nhandled Promise rejection: Container is not defined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Container is not defined

how to solve this error

Comment: Are you use typescript right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

[single-page-app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router)

[single-page-app2](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing)

i hope this is very useful.